# Grails 3.3.8 Spring Security, springSecurityFilterChain issue

Tags: grails

I am working on a Grails project in which started giving me the following error. The error is intermittent. For the first 30 or so minutes there was no issue. I am working on the same views. Any ideas what causes the error below? I can provide additional information.

```
 There was a problem retrieving the current 
 GrailsWebRequest. 
 This usually indicates a filter ordering issue
 (the 'springSecurityFilterChain'
```

**Filter chain config**

```
grails.controllers.upload.maxFileSize=5000000
grails.controllers.upload.maxRequestSize=5000000

// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'org.greenfield.Account'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'org.greenfield.AccountRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'org.greenfield.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/notFound',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/uploads/**',     access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/fonts/**',    access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']]
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/fonts',       filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**',             filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS']
]


grails.plugin.springsecurity.shiro.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.shiro.permissionDomainClassName = 'org.greenfield.Permission'
```

Comment: While I have no idea of the answer, the first thing someone is probably going to ask, is can you post your filter chain config? I'll be interested in the answer to this myself, asbim just starting to upgrade to Grails 3.3.8.

Comment: updated, added filter chain config